# Prove the inequality $\deg{P(x)}\cdot \deg{Q(x)}\cdot \deg{R(x)}\ge 656$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Let three non-constant polynomials $P(x),Q(x),R(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$, and suppose that the equation $P(x)Q(x)R(x)=2015$ has $49$  distinct integer roots.

Prove that
$$\deg{P(x)}\cdot \deg{Q(x)}\cdot \deg{R(x)}\ge 656$$

Comment: Let $x_1,\ldots,x_{49}$ be distinct integer rootsd.
Since $2015=5\cdot 13\cdot 31$, we have $P(x_i)\in S:=\{1,5,13,31,65,155,403,2015\}$. Since $6\cdot 8<49$, the pigeon-hole principle tells us that for $P$ (and as well $Q$, $R$) there must exist one value $y_P\in S$ that occurs at least $7$ times, wlog. this happens for $x_1,\ldots,x_7$. Therefore $\deg P\ge 7$.
By the same argument $\deg Q\ge 7$ and $\deg R\ge 7$.
This gives us at least $\ge 343$.

Comment: maybe have $-1,-5,-13,-31,-65,-155,-403,-2015$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Not sure if this was meant to be a hint,  but we also have $\deg P + \deg Q + \deg R = 49$, so it shouldn't be too hard to finish it then. Exepted that we also should consider the negative values, so that we actually get that the degrees are greater than 4.

Comment: Let $x=\deg(P)$ , $y=\deg(P)$ and $z=\deg(P)$ hence $x+y+z=49$ and $x,y,z\geq 7$ and from these contraints we have $xyz\geq 1715$ using [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%5B%7Bx*y*z%2Cx%3E%3D7%2Cy%3E%3D7%2Cz%3E%3D7%2Cx%2By%2Bz%3D49%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%5D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, composing all comments together:

Let $x_i, i=1..49$ be distinct integer roots.

1. $x_i \in \mathbb Z$ ; $P(x),Q(x),R(x)\in \mathbb Z[x] \Rightarrow P(x_i),Q(x_i),R(x_i)\in \mathbb Z$ for all $i$.
2. Since $2015 = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 31$ we have for all $i$ that $P(x_i) \in S:=\{ \pm 1,\pm 5,\pm 13, \pm 31, \pm 65, \pm 155, \pm 403,\pm 2015 \}$. Note that $|S|= 16$.
3. Let $k =deg(P)>0$. We know that for each $s$ there are no more than $k$ distinct numbers $x$ such $P(x)=s$. So there are no more than $16k$ distinct numbers $x$ such that $P(x) \in S$. Then we have $16k \geq 49 \Rightarrow deg(P) = k \geq 4$ since $k$ is integer. Same we can say for $deg(Q)$ and $deg(R)$.
4. Additionally we have $deg(P)+deg(Q)+deg(R) \geq 49$ since there are at least 49 roots (some roots may be multiple roots).
5. We end with optimization problem:

   find $min(x \cdot y \cdot z)$ given $ x,y,z \geq 4$ and $x+y+z \geq 49 $ and $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z$.

   Solution of this simple problem tells that $min(x \cdot y \cdot z) = 656 $ (and it is realized for $(x,y,z) = (4,4,41)$ and it permutations).

All this derivations are contained in comments but in implicit form thats why I posted explicit answer. If you want upvote, please do it on comments.